# Getting column ambiguously defined error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am getting **" column ambiguously defined"** error when I try running the below query:

```
SELECT ROWNUM, sub.* FROM
          (SELECT orm.msg_id,
    --Facility
          msh.sending_corp as source_system,
          msh.sending_corp,
          msh.sending_facility,
          fsub.east_west_flag,
          fsub.account_number,
          fsub.HLAB_NUM,
          fsub.cid,
          fsub.facility_id,
    --Patient
          pid.EXT_PAT_ID,
          pid.patient_name,
          pid.ssn,
          pid.sex,
          pid.date_of_birth,
          pat.spectra_mrn,
          pat.patient_id,
          pv1.attending_doctor,
    --Order
          orc.order_control,
          orc.EXT_ORDER_ID,
          orc.draw_date,
          lab.LAB_ORDER_OCC_ID,
          pv1.modality,
          lab.MSG_SENT_TO_LAB_YN as order_transmit_status,
          xref.REQUISITION_NO,
          lab_test.DRAW_DT as src_draw_date,
          xref.REQUISITION_NO as src_req_number,
    --Test
          lab_test.LAB_ORDER_OCC_ID as order_id_of_ordertest_tbl,
          lab_test.LAB_ORDER_OCC_TEST_ID,
          emr.emr_order_number as emr_test_order_id_ordtst_tbl,
          lab_test.TEST_SENT_TO_LAB_YN as test_transmit_status,
          SUBSTR(obr.EXT_TEST_ORDER_ID, 1, DECODE(INSTR(obr.EXT_TEST_ORDER_ID,'-',1,1),0,LENGTH(obr.EXT_TEST_ORDER_ID),INSTR(obr.EXT_TEST_ORDER_ID,'-',1,1)-1)) EXT_TEST_ORDER_ID,
          obr.test_details,
          --obr.priority,
          SUBSTR(obr.collection_time,1,4) as collection_time,
          NVL(src.internal_code, obr.specimen_source) as specimen_source,
          NVL2(lab_test.LAB_ORDER_OCC_TEST_ID,tst.SPECIMEN_TYPE,SUBSTR(tst.container, 1, INSTR(tst.container,'|',1,1)-1) || '^' || SUBSTR(tst.container, INSTR(tst.container, '|',-1,1)+1)) AS collector_identifier,
          obr.EXT_TEST_DETAILS,
          obr.frequency,
          NVL2(lab_test.LAB_ORDER_OCC_TEST_ID,tst.test_code,tst.test_code) AS test_code,
          NVL2(lab_test.LAB_ORDER_OCC_TEST_ID,tst.test_name,tst.test_name) AS test_name,
          NVL2(lab_test.LAB_ORDER_OCC_TEST_ID,tst.test_id,tst.test_id) AS test_id,
          obr.sl_no,
          xref.ACCESSION_NO,
          tst.order_flag,
          obr.ORDERING_DOCTOR,
          DECODE(INSTR(obr.EXT_TEST_ORDER_ID,'-',1,1),0,NULL,SUBSTR(obr.EXT_TEST_ORDER_ID, INSTR(obr.EXT_TEST_ORDER_ID,'-',1,1)+ 1)) as reschedule_count,
    --Diag
          lab_test_dg.LAB_ORDER_OCC_TEST_ID,
          dg1.diagnosis_code,
          icd.ICD9_CODE,
          icd.ICD9_CODE_ID,
          icd.description,
          dg1.diagnosis_coding_method,
          dg1.obr_sl_no

        FROM INT_RCV_ORM orm
    --Facility
        INNER JOIN INT_RCV_ORM_MSH msh ON orm.MSG_ID = msh.msg_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT * FROM (
        (SELECT rank() OVER (PARTITION BY fac.facility_id ORDER BY DECODE(fad.ACCOUNT_TYPE,'NA','ZZZ',fad.ACCOUNT_TYPE)) RNK,
        fad.* FROM facility fac ,Facility_Account_Detail fad WHERE
             fac.facility_id = fad.facility_id and 
            UPPER(fac.facility_status) IN ('A')
        AND UPPER(fad.ACCOUNT_TYPE) NOT IN ('STAFF','WATER')))
        WHERE RNK  = 1
        )fsub
        ON fsub.facility_id   = msh.sending_facility
    --Patient
        INNER JOIN INT_RCV_ORM_PID pid  ON orm.msg_id = pid.msg_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN patient pat ON pid.EXT_PAT_ID = pat.EXTERNAL_ID
        INNER JOIN INT_RCV_ORM_PV1 pv1  ON orm.msg_id = pv1.msg_id
    --Orders
        INNER JOIN INT_RCV_ORM_ORC orc  ON orm.msg_id = orc.msg_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EMR_LAB_ORDER_DTL emr ON emr.emr_order_number = orc.EXT_ORDER_ID
        left outer join LAB_ORDER_OCC lab on  lab.LAB_ORDER_OCC_ID= emr.LAB_ORDER_OCC_ID
        left outer join ORDER_OCC_REQUISITION_X_REF xref on xref.LAB_ORDER_OCC_ID=lab.LAB_ORDER_OCC_ID 

    --Order Test
        INNER JOIN INT_RCV_ORM_OBR obr  ON orm.msg_id = obr.msg_id
        left outer join LAB_ORDER_OCC_TEST lab_test on lab_test.LAB_ORDER_OCC_ID = xref.LAB_ORDER_OCC_ID
        AND emr.emr_order_number = SUBSTR(obr.EXT_TEST_ORDER_ID, 1, DECODE(INSTR(obr.EXT_TEST_ORDER_ID,'-',1,1),0,LENGTH(obr.EXT_TEST_ORDER_ID),INSTR(obr.EXT_TEST_ORDER_ID,'-',1,1)-1)) AND lab_test.draw_dt = TO_DATE(orc.draw_date,'YYYYMMDD')
        LEFT OUTER JOIN test tst ON tst.test_code = SUBSTR(obr.test_details,1,INSTR(obr.test_details,'^',1,1)-1) AND NVL(tst.inactive_date,TRUNC(SYSDATE)) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND tst.orderable_yn = 'Y' AND (tst.test_flag LIKE '%P%' OR tst.test_flag LIKE '%T%')
        LEFT OUTER JOIN source src ON src.source_name = obr.specimen_source AND src.test_id = tst.test_id
    --Order Test Diag
        LEFT OUTER JOIN INT_RCV_ORM_DG1 dg1  ON orm.msg_id = dg1.msg_id AND dg1.obr_sl_no = obr.sl_no
        left outer join LAB_ORDER_OCC_TEST_DIAG lab_test_dg on lab_test_dg.LAB_ORDER_OCC_TEST_ID = lab_test.LAB_ORDER_OCC_TEST_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ICD9_CODE icd ON icd.ICD9_CODE = dg1.diagnosis_code

    WHERE orm.msg_id BETWEEN in_start_batch_id AND in_end_batch_id
      AND orm.msg_id  NOT IN (SELECT msg_id FROM GTT_ERROR_RCV_LOG)
      AND orm.PROCESSING_STATUS != 'E'
    ORDER BY msg_id) sub
    LOG ERRORS INTO ERR$_GTT_RCV_ORDER ('RCV_INSERT_GTT_ERROR') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Query is within the procedure to populate temporary tables.Suggestions please.
I am getting

> column ambiguously defined

Comment: Remove a small part, try again. Did the error disappear? If not, remove some more etc.

Comment: In `ORDER BY msg_id` , you should use alias for `msg_id`, maybe `orm.msg_id`

Comment: maybe the last part of your query `ORDER BY msg_id` ? I am very much sure, if you use Editors, they give you the line number as well for the error

Comment: You're getting `LAB_ORDER_OCC_TEST_ID` from two tables, for a start.You need to debug this, it isn't really appropriate to dump code and ask us to read it more thoroughly than you can. It isn't really a question - the answer is 'you have a repeated column name or alias...'

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This Error occurs if you use `JOIN` and column without alias in any of the clause.

Please recheck the query. 
My suspicion:

```
WHERE orm.msg_id BETWEEN `in_start_batch_id` AND `in_end_batch_id`
      AND orm.msg_id  NOT IN (SELECT msg_id FROM GTT_ERROR_RCV_LOG)
      AND orm.PROCESSING_STATUS != 'E'
    ORDER BY `msg_id`
```

The question is harder to solve without the data model.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with

```
ORDER BY msg_id
```

msg_id is a field on several tables that I can see. It doesn't know which one to use.